# SVN: Why do I get "svn: E170013" when using WSL2 running Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: svn, wsl-2, ubuntu-22.04

When I try to commit or update source code with SVN within WSL2 running an instance of Ubuntu 22.04, SVN (after asking for credentials) simply hangs.
I then have to kill the task with Ctrl + c and then I see the following:

> svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL ....

Together with

> svn: E200015: Caught signal

I am running SVN version *1.14.1 (r1886195)* and I have updated the /etc/hosts file to point to the SVN server.

I have tried re-isntalling SVN and ssh, but it does not seem to fix anything.
Does anyone have any clue what I should do to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you ping the repo URL? First make sure this is not a network issue.

Comment: Yes, I can ping the URL and SVN works on windows.